# submersion, density-perserving,

Tags: probability, differential-geometry

In Rerference http://www.jstor.org/stable/2243135, Theorem 1 says Let $t: M \rightarrow N$ be a $C^\infty$ function. Then $t$ is density-preserving if and only if $t$ is an almost submersion.

I want to know waht's density preserving, is it that the density of $N$ equals to the density of $M$?

Comment: Since you seem to be new to M.SE: please put in some effort before asking a question.  Otherwise, users will likely downvote your question, or simply not answer at all.

Answer (score 1):

Purely to get this question off of the unanswered queue...

Allow me to quote nearly verbatim from the top of the second page of the linked article (pg 689) -- a.k.a. the same page as the statement of Theorem 1:

> DEFINITION: Let $t \colon M \to N$ be a function between manifolds.  $t$ is *density-preserving* if for every probability distribution on $M$ which has a density, the transformed probability distribution on $N$ has a density.